# Woocommerce Subscriptions: User cancels product 76 subscription, then cancels all other Woocommerce subscriptions

Tags: php, loops, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'custom_subscription_status_change', 10, 3);

function custom_subscription_status_change($subscription_id, $new_status, $old_status) {
    // Check if it's one of the subscriptions you want to monitor (ID 76)
    if ($subscription_id == 76) {
        // Load the subscription object
        $subscription = wcs_get_subscription($subscription_id);

        // Check if the new status is 'cancelled'
        if ($new_status == 'cancelled') {
            // Cancel the other subscription (ID 77)
            $other_subscription_id = 77;
            $other_subscription = wcs_get_subscription($other_subscription_id);
            
            if ($other_subscription) {
                $other_subscription->cancel_order();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when the user subscribed to both product 76 and product 77 subscriptions and when cancelled product 76 subscriptions from my account /subscription tab /actions tab then cancelled all the other subscriptions in woocommerce subscription, but this provided code doesn't work. Please help me to fixed this code.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code as first function argument is the subscription object, but not the subscription ID.

When a customer cancels a subscription, to cancel all other subscriptions, try:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'custom_subscription_status_change', 10, 3);
function custom_subscription_status_change( $subscription, $new_status, $old_status ) {
    // When a subscription is cancelled by the customer
    if ( $new_status === 'cancelled' && ! is_admin() ) {
        // Remove action to avoid an infinite loop
        remove_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'custom_subscription_status_change', 10, 3);

        // Loop through all customer subscriptions
        foreach( wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $subscription->get_user_id() ) as $subscription_id => $subscription ) {
            // Cancel all other subscriptions for the customer
            if ( $subscription->get_id() != $subscription_id && $subscription->get_status() !== 'cancelled' ) {
                $subscription->cancel_order("Subscription {$subscription->get_id()} cancelled by the customer, cancel this subscription.");
            }
        }
        // add back the action
        add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'custom_subscription_status_change', 10, 3);
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Related: [Subscriptions documentation - Status Change Actions](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#section-2)